# Replacing double backslash and brackets in Python

Tags: python, pandoc, multimarkdown

I am trying to write a script that could convert things like `\\[` or `\\]` to `$$` in order to convert a MultiMarkdown document to Pandoc markdown document that could display equations in HTML. I am using Python to find all instances of these characters using

```
 matchstring=r'\\['
 re.sub(matchstring,'$$',content)
```

However I run into the following error:

```
unexpected end of regular expression:line 15:matchstring=re.compile(r'\\[')
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190:
return _compile(pattern, flags)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 245:
raise error, v # invalid expression
```

most likely because of the last `[` I have in there. Does anyone know a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pandoc -f markdown_mmd -t markdown
```

will do this for you!  (For pandoc >= 1.11)

Comment: Oh Wow! thats great to know.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `[`:

```
matchstring=re.compile(r'//\[')
```

Or better yet, use:

```
content.replace("//[", "$$")
```

and don't involve regex at all.

Comment: How would I go about multiple replace in the document? I have different patterns to match. Shoudl I be doing `content.replace("//[", "$$")` `content.replace("//]", "$$")` for all the patterns I want to match or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Just realised that I could use `content.replace("//[", "$$")).replace(r"\\]", "$$")` to do multiple iterations of replace. Thanks @Igor!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you write `r'//['`, not `r'\\['`,
but anyway try better this:

```
matchstring.replace(r'\\[', '$$').replace(r'\\]', '$$')
```

Comment: My bad. I mixed up forward and backslashes. Fixed them in the question

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a "[" within your regex, I would assume it would be required to have an escape for it as it is used within regular expression.

try one of the following:

```
content = "testing123//]testing456"
matchstring = "//]"
result = content.replace(matchstring, "$$")
print result
```

or

```
content = "testing123//]testing456"
matchstring = '(//\])'
result = re.sub(matchstring,'$$',content)
print result
```

Either should work for your purpose.

Comment: just saw the next comment.. if it is just the "]" characters that are to be replaced, then try: matchstring = "\]"

Comment: the above comment was for the first example. For the second, use matchstring = '(\\])'

Comment: To deal with both at the same time ("[" & "]"), try using something like this: re.sub('(\\]|\\[)','$$',content)